# Drupal View as a form item?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-forms

I have been googling for this quite a long time and I kept finding result about how to embed forms into the Views. And I need the exact oposite of this.

I need multiselect within a form. Items in this multiselect come from a View and I need the option to filter them as well. I need the ability display any field in that multiselect, so it has to be really fancy, jQuery/AJAX driven. Have you ever heard of anything like this? Thanks a lot.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to help but I need a little more info:

Which version of Drupal are you using?

What is the form? Is it a create node form, or something else?

What are the items you are selecting from? Are they nodes, or something else?

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer the D7 version. Yes, it is a node form and those items are users. If you use Facebook - try to imagine the friends selection window, for example when you create a new event and want to invite friends. I need sth like that. It actually does not need to be View, as I have realised recently, just a special form item - multiple checkboxes with some information for every single one (this information has to be HTML formatted, picture, text) and filters.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of information you're trying to allow users to select, you can use a node reference or user reference field and provide a view to that field that will generate the options to select.

So, if you want the form to allow people to select users: create a view that is a list of users, create a user reference field in that content type and select the new view as the available options.

Comment: I knew about this option but I am not sure whether it is possible to display **any** field in that view (select users by their names and images) and also whether I can use view filters in this view (as per my requirements). Apparently, there is more that one module for referencing in D7 - can you recommend which one is better for this?